# Injecting javascript to the view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a div item in my view called 'divStatus' which I want to update from controller, I mean, I want to append info to the existing content in the div so from controller I do:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PerformDiagnostic(TestsModel model)
        {
            var script = "$('#divStatus').append('hello World!');";
            return JavaScript(script);
        }
```

Ok, this is working perfectly but it is not working when I want to do something a little more complicated, for example, imagine below case:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PerformDiagnostic(TestsModel model)
    {
        var script = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            script = "$('#divStatus').append('" + "<h1>hello World" + i.ToString() + "!</h1>');";
        }
        return JavaScript(script);
    }
```

Obviously after executing it, string "hello World9!" is added to the divStatus control because it is the last executed so when returning with JavaScript(script) it prints to the view the last command executed. But what happens if I want to print the strings originated at each loop? for example, it want to obtain the following:

hello World0!

hello World1!

hello World2!

hello World3!

hello World4!

hello World5!

hello World6!

hello World7!

hello World8!

hello World9!

I have spent a lot of days trying to do it, and it is a nightmare, could anybody tell me how to get rif of this situation? I highly appreciate. I have tried to some way do something similar to the return does, but I have no idea how to tell to the view: "hey! you must update div control with the new info appended!"

Also I have tried to use signalr framework to do this, and I have read partially its tutorial, but I do not understand, I think there is no a very simple and little example showing how to update a control, for example in my case, a div, from the controller. Also If somebody expert in signalr can provide me a very simple example done in signalr I also highly appreciate.

I am using asp.net mvc 4 razor

**This is my real case:**

Controller:

```
    public bool DoPing(string hostNameOrAddress)
    {
        bool connectionOk = false;

        try
        {
            System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping pinger = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();

            connectionOk = pinger.Send(hostNameOrAddress).Status == System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            connectionOk = false;
        }

        return connectionOk;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PerformWTGTests(TestsModel model)
    {
        bool result = false;            

        using (ConfigContext context = new ConfigContext())
        {
            List<Machine> mCollection = context.Machines.Where(m => m.TypeId == 1).ToList();
            foreach (Machine machine in mCollection)
            {
                result = this.DoPing(machine.IP);

                string res =  result ? "PASSED" : "FAILED";
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("IP: {0} - Result: {1}", machine.IP, res, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

                // After I obtain the result for each machine I want to update the control in view, in my case a div, saying if it is passed or failed, so I need to do this at each loop for each machine.
                // Below I have tried to update control in view using it but no works
                ViewBag.JS = "updateProgressWindow('" + machine.IP + "','" + res + "');";
            }
        }

        if (result)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. The C# code in your action method will always be executed well before client-side scripts are executed. Your best bet will be simply injecting the loop in the script:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PerformDiagnostic(TestsModel model)
{
    var script = "for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) $('#divStatus').append('<h1>hello World' + i + '</h1>');";
    return JavaScript(script);
}
```

Comment: ok, but your solution is good for this case, I mean, to resolve a simple case like this but imagine in the controller I do more complicated things, like query database using entity framework and in this case will be not suitable doing as you say. Anway for easy things to do what you say is totally correct.

Comment: Without any further details on what complicated cases your controller is trying to handle, I will not be able to help you further. Glad this helped you though. Please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: See my post updated. As you can see I have a collection of machines. I want to check if every of them is alive by pinging to it and for each machine then I want to update the div control in the view to inform the user of the progress and inform for each machine if it has passed or failed when trying to do the ping. As you can see, this is a more complex situation in where using your approach would be very difficult and not suitable. I am totally sure that I am not the only one with this kind of situation that want to update the ui from the controller.

Comment: I have tried a lot of solution, but always all of them finish with the same kind of problem, for example, i have tried to have a script function in the view and call it from the controller at each loop but also without success. Also another think i do not understand is why i cannot call from the controller a javascript function with parameters but it is another thread I opened...

Comment: Ok, I have accepted your proposal as a solution but for only easy cases but consider that your case is not working for more complex cases similar to my real one.